# What is wrong with this nested routing?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement nested routing in a react app, using this code:

```
  <>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="plans" element={<Plans />} />
        <Route path="trainers" element={<Trainers />} />
        <Route path="store" element={<StoreMain />} />
        <Route path="myportal" element={<MyPortal />}>
          <Route path="workouts" element={<WorkoutsFetch />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="signup" element={<Signup />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
```

In the MyPortal component there is a link where it leads the user to workouts component. This component renders a div, which contains fetched data. The components itself works flawlessly, but the part that doesn't work is when I try to go to that route - it doesn't render anything. The URL changes to /myportal/workouts, but the pages doesn't updates. Any suggestions?

I looked into other Stack Overflow solutions where I tried to do this:

```
<Route path="myportal/*" element={<MyPortal />}> // - with /* after the path
  <Route path="workouts" element={<WorkoutsFetch />} />
</Route>
```

But this didn't help my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your route is a child of myportal, you'll need to index it, putting it as:
<Route index element={} /> should resolve your issue.

Make sure you also have an outlet in the parent: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet

Comment: I wasn't aware that I needed to place the <Outlet> in the parent component. That resolved my issue. Thank You!

Comment: No worries! Make it as answered :)